Showing that a statistic of a random set is measurable
I would like to describe a random set that almost surely contains the origin by supremum of magnitudes of all points in the path connected component of the random set containing the origin. In other words, I am looking for the radius of the smallest ball centered at the origin that completely contains that path connected component of the set. This only makes sense if the radius is a measurable quantity. How do I show that the radius is a measurable random variable?
My idea is to consider a topology on the space of paths from the origin so that the space is separable. Then, I can test a countable number of paths to see if they are contained in the random set. Is it possible / meaningful to do this?
